# Login: How to check user is logged in or not

Tags: php, authentication

I am using the **loaded ecommerce**. i want to show some content when user is logged in. so i want to check that user is logged in or not. how can we check the it? Plz Help

Comment: What have you tried? Hovever, take into account to use cookies or session's value (with all advantage and problems that they brings to you)

Comment: I guess you have to add a session. I don't work php, but I programmed some J2ME applicaitons, we used to use sessions to check the status of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Track this Login scenario with session variable.........

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   echo 'username';
}else{
   redirect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how is your log in set up? when i say that is how do you tell when the user is logged in our not, that is if you have it set up in the 1st place. If not you would parse the user input and check it against the records in the db if everything is set then you would assign the username to a $_SESSION var. 
PHP Code:

```
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $username_they_entered;
```

now if you are testing whether they are logged in or not you would simply go
PHP Code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) 
{ 
//print something you only want the person logged in to see 
//maybe there username 
print "Welcome $_SESSION['user_name']" ; 
} 
else 
{ 
print 'Welcome Guest. Would you like to register?' ; 
}
```